# How to send mail at particular date using Service in Android ?

Tags: java, android

I creating app for sending email on particular date using Service class.I have tried and run the its getting runTimeException .How to use service class for send email at particular date.Thanks to appreciate.

Here is my Activity code

```
btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
         btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 strEmail= etEmailId.getText().toString().trim();

                 strServiceName =  etServiceName.getText().toString().trim();
                         strSuppliername= etSupplierName.getText().toString().trim();
                         strReplacementDate= etReplacementDate.getText().toString().trim();
                         strIntervalDays= etInterval_Days.getText().toString().trim();
                         strNextReplacementDate = etNextReplanishmentDate.getText().toString().trim();
                         System.out.println("Data :- " + strServiceName +","+ strSuppliername +","+ strEmail +","+ strReplacementDate +","+ strIntervalDays + "," + strNextReplacementDate);

                         SharedPreferences sharedPref =getSharedPreferences("MyPref_Email", 0);
                         SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = sharedPref.edit();

                         editor1.putString("ServiceName", strServiceName);
                         editor1.putString("Suppliername", strSuppliername);
                         editor1.putString("Email", strEmail);
                         editor1.putString("ReplacementDate", strReplacementDate);
                         editor1.putString("IntervalDays", strIntervalDays);
                         editor1.putString("NextReplacementDate", strNextReplacementDate);

                         editor1.commit();
                         Log.e("Commit is Complit", "Save");

                        // sendEmail();
                         System.out.println("Email Has To Be Sent Successfully");

                         databaseHelper.insertServicenDetails(strServiceName, strSuppliername, strEmail, strReplacementDate, strIntervalDays, strNextReplacementDate);
                         System.out.println("Data Has Been Save Successfully");

                         Intent intent = new Intent(Xyz.this, EmailService.class);
                         startService(intent);

                         System.out.println("Service is start !!!!");



            }
        });


Here is my Email Service class  

public class EmailService extends Service 
{
    private static final String TAG = null;
    private static final String TAG1="MyService";
    private static final String LOGTAG = null;


    String strServiceName ;
    String strSuppliername ;
    String strEmail; 
    String strReplacementDate ; 
    String strIntervalDays; 
    String strNextReplacementDate;

    String strMyServicePref;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void onCreate()
    {
         Toast.makeText(this,"My Service Created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         Log.d(TAG,"ON CREATE");
         super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        startService(intent);
        sendEmail();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }


    protected void sendEmail()
    {
         SharedPreferences sharedPref1 =getSharedPreferences("MyPref_CellNumber", 0);
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = sharedPref1.edit();

         strServiceName=sharedPref1.getString("ServiceName" , "a\n");
         strSuppliername=sharedPref1.getString("Suppliername" , "a\n");
         strEmail=sharedPref1.getString("Email" , "a\n");
         strReplacementDate=sharedPref1.getString("ReplacementDate" , "a\n");
         strIntervalDays=sharedPref1.getString("IntervalDays" , "a\n");
         strNextReplacementDate=sharedPref1.getString("NextReplacementDate" , "a\n");

         Log.e(TAG,"ON CREATE" + strServiceName);
         Log.e(TAG,"ON CREATE" + strSuppliername);
         Log.e(TAG,"ON CREATE" + strEmail);
         Log.e(TAG,"ON CREATE" + strReplacementDate);
         Log.e(TAG,"ON CREATE" + strIntervalDays);
         Log.e(TAG,"ON CREATE" + strNextReplacementDate);

                            String subject = strServiceName;

                            String body = strServiceName+","
                                          +strSuppliername+","
                                          +strReplacementDate+","
                                          +strIntervalDays+","
                                          +strNextReplacementDate;

                           Log.e("body " , " = " + body);

                          Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                          i.setType("message/rfc822");
                          i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{strEmail});
                          i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                          i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , body);

                          try 
                          {
                              startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail...in Service Background"));
                          } 
                          catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) 
                          {
                              Toast.makeText(EmailService.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          }
         }
}


Here is my Log Cat error

08-16 12:53:17.112: E/AndroidRuntime(550): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 12:53:17.112: E/AndroidRuntime(550): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.demo.EmailService@4050d8b8 with Intent { cmp=com.demo/.EmailService }: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
08-16 12:53:17.112: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2052)
08-16 12:53:17.112: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-16 12:53:17.112: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:994)
08-16 12:53:17.112: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-16 12:53:17.112: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-16 12:53:17.112: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-16 12:53:17.112: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 12:53:17.112: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-16 12:53:17.112: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-16 12:53:17.112: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-16 12:53:17.112: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-16 12:53:17.112: E/AndroidRuntime(550): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
08-16 12:53:17.112: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:621)
08-16 12:53:17.112: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:258)
08-16 12:53:17.112: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at com.demo.EmailService.sendEmail(EmailService.java:86)
08-16 12:53:17.112: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at com.demo.EmailService.onStartCommand(EmailService.java:44)
08-16 12:53:17.112: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2039)
08-16 12:53:17.112: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  ... 10 more
```

Comment: but what does the above code tells?have u wriiten broadcast ?if yes plz post

Comment: @DIVA :- Sorry , I did not get you .What you say ?